# Page not found for Drupal form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have enabled a form under modules but accessing the page gives "page not found" error.

sites/default/modules/awesome_form/awesome_form.module

```
function awesome_form_menu(){
 $items['my-new-form'] = array(
    'title' => 'simple form',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('show_form_callback'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'application_file.inc'
  );
  return $items;
}
```

sites/default/modules/awesome_form/application_file.inc

```
function show_form_callback($form, &$form_state){
  $form['test_input'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#title' => 'Name'
  );
  return $form;
}
```

sites/default/modules/awesome_form/awesome_form.info

```
name = Awesome Form
description = Some Test Form
core = 7.x
```

and when I browse to `mysite.com/my-new-form` I get "page not found" error. I also have enabled the module "Awesome Form" under modules. Yet same issue.

Comment: A cutom module in `sites/default/modules`? Shouldn't it be in `sites/all/modules` instead?

Comment: no it should not. and that is not the issue to the problem